# how to get the shortest matching with python (complex non-greedy pattern)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get the shortest matching of the pattern `'''.*?''' is a [[.*?]]` for sentences such as

```
'''fermentation starter''' is a preparation to assist the beginning of the [[fermentation (biochemistry)|fermentation]]. A '''starter culture''' is a [[microbiological culture]]
```

which contains the target string

```
 '''starter culture''' is a [[microbiological culture]]
```

The idea is to get the later string. To do so, I am using the following python code:

```
regex = re.compile("'''.*?''' is a \[\[.*?\]\]")
re.findall(regex, line)
```

However, I am getting the full sentence instead of the shortest pattern. Note that I have added '?' after the qualifier to make the match perform in a non-greedy fashion. Also I can solve it using

```
re.findall(regex, line[30:])
```

in order to escape the first occurrence of `'''.*?'''`, but I am looking for a more natural solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
>>> print re.findall(r"'''(?:(?!''').)*''' is a \[\[.*?\]\]", line)
["'''starter culture''' is a [[microbiological culture]]"]
```

`(?:(?!''').)*` will match 0 or more of any character that does not have `'''` at next position thus **making sure to match shortest match between two `'''`**.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pV1hZ3/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you will not have '[' inside `''' '''` a simple solution is this:

```
regex = re.compile("'''[^[]*?''' is a \[\[.*?\]\]")
regex.findall(line)
```

Or you could do the same thing but with `'`:

```
regex = re.compile("'''[^']*''' is a \[\[.*?\]\]")
regex.findall(line)
```